# Adding items in a function to get a sum

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function

I'm trying to build a pizza application and for the sides, based on what's selected they need to be added up and put into a total. I'm using a function to do this, but its only returning the value from the first selection I make in the combo box, and doesn't go through the if to continue to add the remaining values, I'm confused as to why its doing this. My code for the function is below.

```
 Function sides() As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal

    If cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        total = total + 4.99
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        total = total + 6.99
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        total = total + 6.99
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(3) Then
        total = total + 5.99
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(4) Then
        total = total + 6.99
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(5) Then
        total = total + 7.99
    End If

    Return total
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific issue here is that you are declaring `total` inside that method. As a result, it starts at zero every time you call the method so you only get the most recent value. If you expect the running total to be used each time then its value needs to persist between calls to that method, which means that it must be declared outside that method:

```vb
Private total As Decimal

Function sides() As Decimal
    If cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        total += 4.99D
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        total += 6.99D
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        total += 6.99D
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(3) Then
        total += 5.99D
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(4) Then
        total += 6.99D
    ElseIf cmboSides.SelectedIndex.Equals(5) Then
        total += 7.99D
    End If

    Return total
End Function
```

There are various other things you could do to improve that code too but this addresses the specific issue that you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Store each price as a value then use

```
Dim total As Decimal
For Each item In lstSides.SelectedItems
    total+= CDbl(lstSides.GetItemValue(item))
Next
```

Comment: The items are in a combo box, would it work the same?

Comment: Where does that `GetItemValue` method come from? It's certainly not a member of the WinForms `ListBox` class, which I would have assumed `lstSides` was. Apparently it is a very poorly named `ComboBox`, which doesn't have such a member either.

Comment: @AlexciaLaNae, I hate Hungarian Notation to begin with but, if you're going to use it, at least use it properly. The point is to use a prefix that indicates type but you're using a misleading prefix for a `ComboBox` so it's worse than no type indicator at all.

Comment: I've changed the prefix for the combo box since posting this, but I have it typed it my question specifying that its a combo box. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution, assuming you are actually using a `ListBox` (rather than a `ComboBox` which can't be set to multiselect), is this:

```
Function sides() As Decimal

    Dim total As Decimal

    If lstSides.SelectedIndices.Contains(0) Then total += 4.99
    If lstSides.SelectedIndices.Contains(1) Then total += 6.99
    Etc

    Return total
End Function
```

Your current code will never move to a second `ElseIf` after one has been evaluated as true, similar to a `Case Select` statement.

A much better solution would be to use data binding to a class of `Pizza` with properties such a `Price`, `Availability`, `Size`, etc.